# Syncing two sliders - test if thumbnail is visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

**The background:**

I have two sliders that are connected.
One shows the thumbnails and scrolls up and down (in a loop) using a wrapper and margin-top. It displays 4 thumbnails at a time.
The other scrolls left and right and displays one single item using `display:none;` and `display: block;`.

The sliders are synced, by which I mean if you click the thumbnail the corresponding image in the second slider shows, and if you click next or prev in the big slider the corresponding thumbnail is highlighted. This is working.

**The issue:**
I am struggeling to add a way to scroll the thumbnail slider to the active item if it is not already in the viewport.

Clicking next on the big slider should only scroll the thumbnail slider if the correct thumbnail is not already in the visible area.
Now, the way I thought I could go about this is the following:

Get the current margin-top of the thumbnail slider.
Get the index of the active item.
Get the supposed marginTop of the index item, as well as the previous and next 3.

If `marginTop >= (curindex - 3 * thumbnailHeight)`
and `marginTop <= 0 - (curindex * thumbnailHeight)`
Item should be visible but at the bottom
Or `marginTop <= (curindex + 3) * thumbnailHeight`
and `marginTop >= 0 + (curindex * thumbnailHeight)`
Item should be visible at the top.

Combined (for full code see below):

```
if(((marginTop >= (curindex - 3) * thumbnailHeight) && (marginTop <= 0 - (curindex * thumbnailHeight))) || ((marginTop <= (curindex + 3) * thumbnailHeight) && (marginTop >= 0 + (curindex * thumbnailHeight)))) {
  console.log('no scroll');
} else {
    scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = 0 - (curindex * thumbnailHeight) + 'px';
}
```

**The error:**
There must be some logical flaw that I can not wrap my head around.
The code works fine for the first 4 items, but afterwards it continues to scroll, or if the small slider was already scrolled it also keeps on scrolling downwards. At the end it even overscrolls. The prev function has similar issues, but here it also skips the scroll to the first item.

**Full code:**
https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/nuzsryxd/1/

```js
var thumbnailHeight = 92;
var boxCount = 8;
var maxTop = (boxCount - 3) * thumbnailHeight;
var scrollWrapper = document.getElementById('thumbnail-slider');
var thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail');
var images =  document.getElementsByClassName('image');
var curindex = 0;

window.thumbnail = function(index) {
  for (i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; ++i) {
    thumbnails[i].classList.remove('active');
 }
 thumbnails[index].classList.add('active');

  for (j = 0; j < images.length; ++j) {
    images[j].style.display = 'none';
 }
  images[index].style.display = 'inline-block';
  curindex = index;
};

window.down = function() {
 marginTop = parseInt(scrollWrapper.style.marginTop, 10);
 if(marginTop) {
    if(marginTop == (0 - maxTop)) scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = '0px';
    else scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = (marginTop - thumbnailHeight) + 'px';
  }
 else scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = 0 - thumbnailHeight + 'px';
};

window.up = function() {
 marginTop = parseInt(scrollWrapper.style.marginTop, 10);
 if(marginTop) {
  if(marginTop == 0) scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = 0 - maxTop + 'px';
    else scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = (marginTop + thumbnailHeight) + 'px';
 }
  else scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = 0 - maxTop + 'px';
};

window.next = function() {
  images[curindex].classList.remove('current');
  images[curindex].style.display = 'none';
  if (curindex < boxCount) {
   curindex++;
  } else {
   curindex = 0;
  }
  
  images[curindex].classList.add('current');
  images[curindex].style.display = 'block';
  
   for (i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; ++i) {
     thumbnails[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  thumbnails[curindex].classList.add('active');
    
    // my problem
    
    var marginTop = parseInt(scrollWrapper.style.marginTop, 10);
    if (!marginTop) marginTop = 0;
    
    if(((marginTop >= (curindex - 3) * thumbnailHeight) && (marginTop <= 0 - (curindex * thumbnailHeight))) || ((marginTop <= (curindex + 3) * thumbnailHeight) && (marginTop >= 0 + (curindex * thumbnailHeight)))) {
      console.log('no scroll');
    } else {
     scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = 0 - (curindex * thumbnailHeight) + 'px';
    }
};
            
window.prev = function() {
 images[curindex].classList.remove('current');
  images[curindex].style.display = 'none';
  if (curindex > 0) {
   curindex--;
  } else {
   curindex = boxCount;
  }
  
  images[curindex].classList.add('current');
  images[curindex].style.display = 'block';
  
   for (i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; ++i) {
     thumbnails[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
  thumbnails[curindex].classList.add('active');
    
    // my problem (same issue as above just the other way around)
    
    var marginTop = parseInt(scrollWrapper.style.marginTop, 10);
    if (!marginTop) marginTop = 0;
    
    if(((marginTop >= (curindex - 3) * thumbnailHeight) && (marginTop <= 0 - (curindex * thumbnailHeight))) || ((marginTop <= (curindex + 3) * thumbnailHeight) && (marginTop >= 0 + (curindex * thumbnailHeight)))) {
      console.log('no scroll');
    } else {
     if (curindex >= boxCount - 3) {
       scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = 0 - maxTop + 'px';
      } else {
       scrollWrapper.style.marginTop = 0 - (curindex * thumbnailHeight) + 'px';
      }
    }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none; 
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#thumbnail-sidebar {
  height: 358px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 98px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thumbnail.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.slider-control {
  width: 122px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbnail-slider {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.main-control {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.current {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="up" class="slider-control" onclick="up()">Up</div>
<div id="thumbnail-sidebar">
  <div id="thumbnail-slider">
    <div class="thumbnail active" onclick="thumbnail(0)">0</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="thumbnail(1)">1</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="thumbnail(2)">2</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="thumbnail(3)">3</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="thumbnail(4)">4</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="thumbnail(5)">5</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="thumbnail(6)">6</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="thumbnail(7)">7</div>
    <div class="thumbnail" onclick="thumbnail(8)">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="down" class="slider-control" onclick="down()">Down</div>

<div id="prev" class="main-control" onclick="prev()">Prev</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="main-slider">
    <div class="image current">0</div>
    <div class="image">1</div>
    <div class="image">2</div>
    <div class="image">3</div>
    <div class="image">4</div>
    <div class="image">5</div>
    <div class="image">6</div>
    <div class="image">7</div>
    <div class="image">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="next" class="main-control" onclick="next()">Next</div>
```